# Git-svn unpicked cherries

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, cherry-pick

Given a repository that was previously in SVN and has now been fully converted to Git (ie. currently accessed via "pure" `git` and not `git svn`):

Given a mainline branch and a release branch that diverged from mainline prior to the Git conversion:

Is there any easy way (from Git) to tell which commits are present on the release branch and not on the mainline branch (ie. possible candidates to be cherry-picked back to mainline, when a fix has been made directly to the release branch)?

The problem I see is that commands like `git cherry` (which is apparently the right choice for branches that diverged **after** the Git conversion) expect that complete commits are kept intact, but merges made in SVN prior to the conversion tend to be roll-ups -- basically squashed cherries instead of intact cherries.

In SVN, this is accomplished by inspecting the `svn:mergeinfo` property (usually automatically via tools).  I don't know if this information was preserved during the conversion process, or if there are any tools that know to look for it in an apparently-native-Git repository.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of commits whose *changes* are present in the `release` branch but *not* on `master` – and are therefore candidates for cherry picking – by using `git log --cherry-pick` and the [triple-dot syntax](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#_triple_dot):

```
git log --cherry-pick --right-only master...release
```

Let's break it down:

- `master...release` selects the commits that are reachable from `release` but not `master` and vice versa.
- `--right-only` shows only the commits reachable from the *right side* of the range, in this case the `release` branch
- `--cherry-pick` hides the commits from `release` whose *changes* have already been applied to `master` – i.e. they're considered *patch equivalent*.

The key part here is `--cherry-pick` because that's what causes Git to determine whether a commit has been applied to a branch based on the commit's *patch* and not its SHA-1 hash.

Comment: The point that I was trying to make is that SVN merges are squashed merges -- ie. I am trying to eliminate not a case where a,b,c,d are separate commits on both sides, but a case where a,b,c,d are separate commits on one side and a *different* commit that equals a+b+c+d as a single commit is present on the other side.  Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think the above handles that.